# Mock UIView in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Consider an example when I'm having UIViewController with simple interface:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

When it receives viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear messages it creates and places additional views.

When unit testing it, I want to mock up these views, so I need to change interface to this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) UIView *additionalView1
@property (nonatomic) UIView *additionalView2

@end
```

By doing this I'm moving responsibility of creating additional views to calling side, which, in my opinion, breaks encapsulation.

How can I avoid exposing so much of controller internals?

Comment: Interesting question, I agree this definitely breaks encapsulation. Also, what does "Does it only one possible solution when unit testing view controllers?" mean?

Comment: I've refrased my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support setter injection, you really have to expose it.

There are ways of trying to hide it, or mark it as off-limits. You can wrap the property declarations in `#if DEBUG`. Or you can move them to a class extension in MainViewController_Private.

But I find that these tricks only make the code noisier. So my approach is to go ahead and expose them. As I point out on [Testability, Information Hiding, and the Class Trying to Get Out](https://qualitycoding.org/testability-vs-hiding/), such exposure can be a clue that a class may need to be extracted, or responsibilities shifted. For example, since you want to inject these views, should MainViewController really create them? Maybe the tension is leading us to make a factory, keeping MainViewController ignorant of the details of these views.